# MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist! | Huawei Phone

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

It maybe cause by the ARM GPUs in Huawei Phones, according to this article [ARM GPUs in Huawei phone](https://medium.com/@afd_icl/arm-gpus-in-huawei-phones-cb81280fbbab). And it doesn't happen when i try to run the app in another phone (Pixel API 27 in Android Studio).So What should i do?

#### Logcat show in Huawei Phone

```
2018-12-08 01:22:50.705 25680-25699/? E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2018-12-08 01:22:50.706 25680-25680/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
```

#### gradle Enviroment

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.minram.fucloud_android"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

#### Android studio Enviroment

- Android Studio 3.2.1
- Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 10 10.0

  #### HuaweiPhone
- Android 8.1.0
- EMUI 8.2.0
- Huawei INE-AL00 8.2.0.142

#### All Logcat

```
2018-12-08 02:01:28.036 30822-30822/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2018-12-08 02:01:28.058 30822-30822/? I/zygote64: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false
2018-12-08 02:01:28.084 30822-30822/? D/ActivityThread: Attach thread to application
2018-12-08 02:01:28.152 30822-30822/? D/HwFLClassLoader: get used feature list :/feature/used-list failed!
2018-12-08 02:01:28.152 30822-30822/? D/HwFLClassLoader: USE_FEATURE_LIST had not init! 
2018-12-08 02:01:28.154 30822-30838/? I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.minram.fucloud_android#10259#256
2018-12-08 02:01:28.155 30822-30838/? I/HwApiCacheMangerEx: apicache path=/storage/emulated/0 state=mounted key=com.minram.fucloud_android#10259#0
2018-12-08 02:01:28.192 30822-30822/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
2018-12-08 02:01:28.192 30822-30838/? E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2018-12-08 02:01:28.273 30822-30822/? D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f0c0114, context : com.minram.fucloud_android.SplashScreenActivity@c79fed5, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2018-12-08 02:01:28.274 30822-30822/? D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f0c0114, context : com.minram.fucloud_android.SplashScreenActivity@c79fed5, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2018-12-08 02:01:28.317 30822-30822/? D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{6f94745 token=android.os.BinderProxy@22caade {com.minram.fucloud_android/com.minram.fucloud_android.SplashScreenActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@22caade
2018-12-08 02:01:28.333 30822-30822/? I/hwaps: HwAps: JNI_OnLoad
2018-12-08 02:01:28.337 30822-30822/? D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
2018-12-08 02:01:28.339 30822-30847/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2018-12-08 02:01:28.402 30822-30847/? I/zygote64: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2018-12-08 02:01:28.404 30822-30847/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2018-12-08 02:01:28.404 30822-30847/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2018-12-08 02:01:28.411 30822-30847/? D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2018-12-08 02:01:28.468 30822-30822/? I/ViewRootImpl: jank_removeInvalidNode jank list is null
2018-12-08 02:01:28.469 30822-30822/? W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
2018-12-08 02:01:28.973 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 5
2018-12-08 02:01:29.904 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f0c0114, context : com.minram.fucloud_android.MainActivity@7eaf03e, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2018-12-08 02:01:29.905 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f0c0114, context : com.minram.fucloud_android.MainActivity@7eaf03e, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2018-12-08 02:01:29.908 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/[MainActivity](setFullScreenAdaptWithStatus): start to initial screen
2018-12-08 02:01:29.915 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/[fragmentViewPager](onCreateView): fragment create...
2018-12-08 02:01:29.932 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/HwGalleryCacheManagerImpl: mIsEffect:false
2018-12-08 02:01:29.959 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android I/MainActivity: The radioItem selected! [id:2131165322]
2018-12-08 02:01:29.961 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{e4605a1 token=android.os.BinderProxy@25353c0 {com.minram.fucloud_android/com.minram.fucloud_android.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@25353c0
2018-12-08 02:01:29.971 30822-30847/com.minram.fucloud_android D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
2018-12-08 02:01:29.980 30822-30847/com.minram.fucloud_android D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
2018-12-08 02:01:30.011 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/MainFragment: status bar height:90
2018-12-08 02:01:30.019 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/DiscoverFragment: status bar height:90
2018-12-08 02:01:30.056 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
2018-12-08 02:01:30.056 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
2018-12-08 02:01:30.057 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
2018-12-08 02:01:30.057 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
2018-12-08 02:01:30.100 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/[CircleImageView](init): mBorderColor:2147483647
2018-12-08 02:01:30.100 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/[CircleImageView](init): mFillColor:-1
2018-12-08 02:01:30.100 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/[CircleImageView](init): mStrokeWidth:10
2018-12-08 02:01:30.101 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=25KB, data=29KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.101 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=29KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.101 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.175 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=46KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.175 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=46KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.175 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.176 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2018-12-08 02:01:30.187 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/MeFragment: status bar height:90
2018-12-08 02:01:30.258 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2018-12-08 02:01:30.296 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=121KB, data=86KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.297 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=118KB, data=66KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.298 30822-30847/com.minram.fucloud_android D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2018-12-08 02:01:30.327 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=69KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.327 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=69KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.327 30822-30828/com.minram.fucloud_android I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
2018-12-08 02:01:30.342 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
2018-12-08 02:01:30.395 30822-30847/com.minram.fucloud_android W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7acaf64010 disconnect failed
2018-12-08 02:01:30.526 30822-30822/com.minram.fucloud_android D/ActivityThread: Remove activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{6f94745 token=android.os.BinderProxy@22caade {com.minram.fucloud_android/com.minram.fucloud_android.SplashScreenActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@22caade
```

Comment: Did you found anything about it?

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I solved this issue by upgrading my `Android Studio 3.2.0` to `Android Studio 3.3.1`. Not only this but upgrade the PROJECT level of `build.gradle` from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

Turns out there are solved dependencies only available on later versions of Gradle, for more information you can see this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases).

Comment: I am having classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1' and still the same problem so your answer is not good.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue check the Database initialization if any.

Check "Run" Tab in Android Studio
you can see the cause of Crash.

Nothing to do with Huawei Phone

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Huawei phone. But in my case when I checked the run log, noticed that the crash happens when I start an activity class which is not declared in the Manifest file. Fixing this solved the crash issue with this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the only reason is in the database rules.
I have changed my rules to the following and it works very well:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write
```